# How far can I travel outside Stockholm with unlimited 24-hour TravelCard (Map)?

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, sweden, stockholm

I'd like to buy a (time-based) unlimited Travel Card for the public transport system in Stockholm, Sweden. But it's unclear exactly how far around the center of Stockholm that this card will be valid for.

Since 2018, there are no "zones" for the Stockholm public transport system. In 2022, you can buy "Travel Cards" that are valid for 24-hours, 72-hours, 7-days, or 30-days with unlimited travel. I've read that this card will allow unlimited travel on the following around Stockholm:

1. All Buses,
2. trams,
3. tunnelbana (T-bana),
4. commuter trains, and
5. the Djurgården ferry

However, I've been unable to find a single map that shows all of the stops for the above systems for which the Travel Card is valid. I'd like a map that would allow me to quickly see roughly how many km outside the city center that I can go without having to buy an additional ticket.

Is there a map that shows all of the places you can travel around Stockholm on a Travel Card?

Comment: [There's a map here](https://sl.se/globalassets/sl-spartrafik.pdf) covering all tram, metro, and commuter trains. Although it's not geographically to scale so you'd have to work out which destination is actually furthest.

Comment: @StuartF That's a great map! May I ask where you found it?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield From https://sl.se home page (This is the Stockholm public transport site), click on **Reseplanering**, then **Kartor över SL-trafiken**, and **Spårtrafik**. The map is under **All spårtrafik** link. Don't switch to english version: the map is older and of smaller resolution.

Comment: For the pathologically curious out there, the farthest bus stop I can find (using OpenStreetMap data) is [Ellans vändplan](https://goo.gl/maps/2TJz6nf1TvYE6TVV8) ("Ellan turning circle") located over 100 km as the crow flies from Gustav Adolfs torg, which is the usual "zero point" for road distances from Stockholm.

Comment: There's a couple of other boats you can use as well. For tourists most notably "line 83/83X" which is a trip from Strömkajen (very central location on short walking distance from the central station) out to Vaxholm, which is a tourist-friendly small town. The boat trip goes through some nice areas of the inner Stockholm archipelago and if you are lucky you get to go on one of the old steam ferries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a rail map here, https://sl.se/en/in-english/getting-around/sl-service-network-maps/ .

This does not include buses and ferries though. It only includes all transport on rails. Including buses would render the map unreadable. There are a few hundred bus lines in addition to this.

As said before there are no zones in the SL traffic. You will be able to travel on your commuter card in a radius of about 40-50km from Stockholm City.

In case you want to go to Uppsala, you will have to pay for an additional UL ticket for the amount of zones you want to travel. I was not able to find any good info on this, at least not in English, so I recommend asking in the counter if you plan going there.

If you want to go to Arlanda, the railway and station is owned by a private company and you will have to by an additional ticket if you want to go on or off there.

Comment: @Anders Thanks for the comment. I have updated the text. It appears as if "Bålstatillägget" is removed as well. Unfortunately the English info on the SL homepage is terrible when it comes to UL and tickets in general. I think there is a big room for improvement there.